# JavaScript variable value to a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I know that the following question has been asked many times:

```
<script>
  var myVar = 123;
  <?php $what_is_myVar = myVar ; ?>
</script>
```

My searching results for this question were:

- PHP runs on the server, JavaScript runs on the client…
- Need to use Ajax to pass a JS value...
- This code will never work you…
- Need to set hidden field value…
- Use $_GET[]…

I tried the following, but that didn’t work:

```
<?php $what_is_myVar = "<script>document.write(myVar)</script>"; ?>
```

I couldn’t find anywhere a complete short solution in order to pass the value of `myVar` into `$what_is_myVar`

Please can anyone help me on this issue,

Comment: The correct answer is `Need to use Ajax to pass a JS value.`

Comment: `complete short solution` heh.

Comment: @ Dylan. I can add your reply to my searching results, heh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ajax request, follow the link:
 [5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)